# How to program the serving of two pages, accessible under the same URL, with only one of them getting indexed

Tags: php, html, seo, search-engine, robots.txt

Let's say you have a website hosted on `example.org`. That website has a single page, whose content is static if the client requesting is not logged in, but dynamic (according to the logged client) if the client requesting it is logged in.

To properly handle this in terms of indexing on search engines, we currently thought of creating two separate files, let's say `logged_out.html` and `logged_in.php`. When the URL (e.g. `example.org`) is requested, the PHP code checks if the current user is logged in, and if so, it requires `logged_in.php`, otherwise `logged_out.html`.
The `logged_in.php` has this in its head:

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive">`

As it does not make sense to index websites with dynamic contents in this system.

My question thus basically is how to program the serving / the routing of two pages, accessible under the same URL, with only one of them getting indexed. Such that the SE see only one and completely ignore the other one. Our current solution could be summed up like this:

```
// HTTP Request incoming to https://example.org/sample, which is routed to 
// present file via server configs 

if ($logged_in) {
  require ("logged_in.php") // should never be indexed / crawled
} else {
  require ("logged_out.html") // should be the indexed / crawled page
}

exit();
```

This should result in exclusively the contents of `logged_out.html` being indexed, and that for the URL https://example.org/sample, while the contents of `logged_in.php` should neither be indexed under any URL of example.org, nor be crawled.

Does our approach yield that intended result?

Comment: My question basically is how to program the serving / the routing of two pages, accessible under the same URL, with only one of them getting indexed. Such that the SE see only one and completely ignore the other one. That‘s not a programming-related SEO question?!

Comment: Quote: “Our question is; could this lead to some kind of problems with search engine indexing?” You can edit your question to focus on the measurable programming problem.

Comment: Okay done, added; would you be so kind and reopen it please?

Comment: I can't. It takes a vote. (That said, "Is this the correct approach? Or is maybe some programming on the side of server configs better..?" is a matter of opinion so also off-topic here).

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and note that it says "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.". Reading between the lines of low quality questions and answering them is a good way to satisfy the person asking the question, but not a good way to acheive that mission statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines are not logged in by default and by all means. So the `robots` meta tag on the `logged_in.php` page is not needed.

Also, they are unaware of pages that are being `required` by the main `index.php` they visit. So what will most likely happen, the page `index.php` will get indexed with content of `logged_out.html`. Just make sure to hide the *real* page to prevent duplicate content. Just keep it out of reach for the robots.

This is your code as I understand it.

```php
if ($logged_in) {
  require ("logged_in.php")
} else {
  require ("logged_out.html")
}
```

More thoughts:

In order to truly hide a page from getting indexed you should not expose its URL in links. You should place it in a deny access directory, or out of the web root. It could still be `required` don't worry.

Bonus: you can declare a duplicate page to be [canonical](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls#rel-canonical-link-method) of another.

Comment: Yup you could sum up my code like that. Just wondered if that's enough to keep the robots from scanning the `logged_in.php` file, and that only `logged_out.html` will be scanned for the concerned URL. So I guess your answer means it is indeed enough?

Comment: it's enough for making `index.php` serve the right content for people or robots. the other 2 pages should not be accessed directly to prevent confusion.

Comment: Ok cheers and thanks for the update in your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

A page gets indexed only if

- You have an internal link from another page
- There is an external link to the page
- It's in the sitemap.

---

One way is to have a parameter such as

```
example.com/?logged=true
```

A page with different parameters can be regarded as a different pages (for the Search Engine).  This would work if there will be no internal links to the page with a parameter.

---

The other, better way to do it is to have a session variable that you write to when someone is logged in.  When the Search Engine looks at it, this data is not there.  Your code can set whatever data you need in it and it can retrieve it before presenting the modified page.